# Source for saying Aramaic parts of davening quietly?

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, aramaic, loud-quiet

I remember reading somewhere that there is a kabbalistic tradition to say the parts of davening that are in Aramaic (e.g. the targum in Uva Letziyon) quietly. What is the source for this?

Comment: What about kadish?

Comment: Presumably it doesn't apply to kaddish, but I really have no idea.

Comment: Dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17557/5

Comment: @SethJ That question asks specifically about the Uva Letziyon while this one uses it as an example with respect to a question about a broader rule, so I'd say not a dupe.  Although this question might not be a really valid question since we see that the tradition at least doesn't apply in some cases (kaddish), and maybe doesn't apply in any case besides Uva Letziyon.

Comment: See Taz (OC 132:1,לפי שכל שהוא בלשון תרגום אין לאומרו ברבים כן כתב בספר הזוהר, citing Zohar, *T'ruma* 132b), as well as the *P'ri M'gadim* (OC *Mishb'tzos Zahav* ad loc.) who discusses alternative reasons. See also *Beit Yosef* (OC 59). (If I get around to it, I'll write up an answer. If someone beats me to it, that's great too).

Answer (score 2):

The Rama in Orach Chaim siman 132 seif 1 says that in Uvah LeTzion (kedusha de'sidra) the parts of the kedusha that are translated into Aramaic should not be said aloud.

The Mishnah Berurah sk4 says that the Aramaic should be said as an individual since "everything that is in Aramaic should not be said *berabim*"

The perush Matok MiDvash explains the reason behind this halacha according to the Zohar (chelek 2 132b) which states that the shoresh (root) of Aramaic is from the *sitra achah* and we need to diminish the power of the *sitra achah* by means of reciting it as an individual.

As an aside: The Mishna Berurah concludes that if an individual is not praying with a tzibur they are allowed to say the Aramaic aloud. This is quoted from the Sha'arei Teshuva. However according to other explanations for the Rama's halacha (some brought in the Peri Megadim) you might not be allowed to say the Aramaic aloud even when not praying with a tzibur

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara in Shabbos 12b mentions that one shouldn't daven in Aramaic because angels don't understand Aramaic.  The angels "carry" the prayers to G-d, and if they don't understand them, they won't take them because they don't want to take unacceptable prayers.  However, in prayers which are a davar sheb'kedusha, the prayers are listened to directly by Hashem, and therefore Kaddish is said aloud in Aramaic (along the lines of the gemara there, that davening in the presence of the sick person can be done in Aramaic because Hashem is with the sick).